# How many android devices can I use with a single google account?

Tags: android, google-accounts

As the title, I want to know how many android devices I can use with a single google account. Is there any limit as Apple Appstore Id?

Comment: This question might be better off on android.stackexchange.com

Comment: [Here's an answer to a similar question](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/8735/267) where the author has 10 Android devices tied to one account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no limit.  I've heard of people who use the same account on at least three different devices.